# RX Java all elements in a flowable reach certain condition

Tags: java, amazon-s3, rx-java

I am trying to perform a [MultiPart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuJava.html) to S3 in an asynchronous way with RxJava 2.

```
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2"
```

I have a `Flowable` of parts. For each part I call a method on a `TransferManager` object which returns immediately an `Upload` object.

`Upload::isDone` method javadoc looks like:

`/**
     * Returns whether or not the transfer is finished (i.e. completed successfully,
     * failed, or was canceled).
     *
     * @return Returns <code>true</code> if this transfer is finished (i.e. completed successfully,
     *         failed, or was canceled).  Returns <code>false</code> if otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isDone();`

This is what I am trying to do:

`TransferManager`:

```
public class TransferManager {

    public Upload transfer(Part part) {
        return new Upload();
    }
}
```

`Part`:

```
public class Part {}
```

`Upload`:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Upload {
    public boolean isDone() {
        return new Random().nextInt(10) == 1;
    }
}
```

This is what I am doing:

```
  TransferManager tm = new TransferManager();
        Flowable.just(new Part(), new Part(), new Part(), new Part(), new Part())
                .map(part -> tm.transfer(part))
                .subscribe(upload -> {
                    do {
                    } while(!upload.isDone());
                });
```

What will be the proper RxJava way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you want to know when `upload.isDone()` and after that do some action in subscribe

```
.map(part -> tm.transfer(part))
.filter(upload -> upload.isDone())
.subscribe(upload -> {...});
```

I think, this can help